# Why is an object literal said to be incompatible with an indexed map after being assigned in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I've run into some weird situation in my TypeScript code:

```
var a : { [name: string]: any } = { a: 'A' }; // WORKS!

interface T { [name: string]: any };
var b : T = { a: 'A' };                       // WORKS!

interface Q<a> { [name: string]: a };
var c : Q<any> = { a: 'A' };                  // WORKS!

var d = { a: 'A' };
c = d;                                        // DOESN'T WORK
```

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with it?

```
Error   1   Cannot convert '{ a: string; }' to 'Q<any>':
    Index signatures of types '{ a: string; }' and 'Q<any>' are incompatible.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you considered:

```
var d = { a: 'A' };
```

The type of `d` would be inferred as:

```
var d: { a : string };
```

**For TypeScript to declare two types to be identical, when they are index signatures, both must be of the identical kind with identical types. (from 3.8.2 in the specification)**

Thus this does not work:

```
c = d;
```

Because it is actually being seen as these two type definitions:

```
{ [name: string] : any } = { a : string };
```

Those are not identical (as they are not identical index signatures).

When you create and set a value directly on a strongly typed variable (like `c`), the type is well known.

If you added another test:

```
var e: { a: string } = { a: 'A'};
e = d;
```

You'd see how `e` will accept the value of `d` without warning.
c = e;

The other sets are working because you've declared the types explicitly, so the type is being inferred correctly (and works as you've seen). That behavior would be like another language where you have a type like `int` for example: `int myVar = 6;`. In that case, `6` would be treated as an `int` even if it could have been represented as a `byte` for example.

Comment: Isn't there a duck-typing thing somewhere in TypeScript? As long as surface of a source object is compatible with a target object it should be allowed to assign it, as far as I remember. If so, Q<any> is compatible with any plain object since it is just a definition of a plain object in terms of indexes.

Comment: They both do not share an index signature as I mentioned. It's very explicit in the documentation, and I wouldn't expect duck-typing to override that behavior.

Comment: Thanks @basarat, I updated the declaration to be specifically a `string` as you pointed out.